# Restrict the useable screen area in windows 10

Tags: windows, desktop

How can I restrict windows from using a certain area of one monitor in Windows 10?

I have a setup with four monitors, three in a row and one just above the middle one. On the rightmost monitor I have some widgets which show me system information, which I want visible all the time. When I open e.g. a second instance of VS Code, it opens up in fullscreen mode on the rightmost monitor, which I don't like.

Windows Vista came with its own widgets and the possibility to place them on a sidebar which prevented fullscreen windows from using this space. Is there any setting or app which mimics this behavior on Windows 10 and maybe later?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great solution for this: https://www.netzwelt.de/tutorial/170222-windows-10-so-aktiviert-sidebar-gadgets.html

Download: https://www.netzwelt.de/software-download/59304-8gadgetpack.html

This free software mimics the Windows Vista Widgets Bar in Windows 8 and up (including 10 and 11). I removed all widgets from it, moved it to "Monitor:" 3 (the rightmost in my setup), set it to be "always on top", but without "show over other windows". Then I adjusted the width to what I need and now any window I put in FullScreen mode on screen 3 takes up all space without the sidebar area.
[image: rightmost screen]

I'm not the developer of the software and don't even know him/her, so I can't answer any questions in particular to bugs and enhancements.